# Prevent Autoescape of inline <SPAN> element in PYCHARM

Tags: python, html, pycharm

CODE (ImageLink) : https://ibb.co/s9sK1sx

In Pycharm on rendering the html_buffer to html_file, ***results in autoescaping of inline span element***.

**CODE:**

```
 cS_color = f'<span style="color: red">"-cS"</span>'
 <td> cS_color</td>#table row element

 with open(htmlpath_out , "w") as fh:
    fh.write(_template)
```

How to prevent Autoescape of inline SPAN element in Pycharm? :

```
<td><span style="color: red">;"-cS"</span></td>  

gets rendered as :

<td>&lt;span style="color: red"&gt;"-cS"&lt;/span&gt;</td>
```